# How to display size color wise?

Tags: reactjs

[image: This is frontend view][image: this is 2 product variant]

I have color and size but here i want to display data condition base.
when I will click color then show that color's size data.
How to solve this.

here I have two color Black and Green now when I will click Black then show that size and when I will click green then show that size data

Comment: ok I sent front-end view

Comment: Please check main pic here i updated, and kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some example like your array and made a solution hope this works for you

live example - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-goldberg-ghd3h)

answer update - I updated this example with radio buttons

```
export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState([]);

  const data = [
    {
      color: { id: 1, colorName: "black" },
      size: [
        {
          colorSize: "small "
        },
        {
          colorSize: "medium "
        },
        {
          colorSize: "large "
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      color: { id: 2, colorName: "red" },
      size: [
        {
          colorSize: "Large"
        },
        {
          colorSize: "Extra large"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  console.log(size);
  const handleBtn = (e) => {
    const id = e?.target.id;
    setSize(data[id]?.size);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main-dev">
        {data.map((item, i) => (
          <button id={i} onClick={(e) => handleBtn(e)}>
            {item?.color?.colorName}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Size</h4>
        {size?.length ? (
          <>
            {size.map((item, i) => (
              <p>{item?.colorSize}</p>
            ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          "Click Button to see sizes"
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But My data come from state given below code:
 const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const { loading, error, product, variants } = productDetails
here  into the variants  all data stored  such as colors size .
Now do I map the variants?

Comment: Do you mean all the colors, sizes, and other data in `productDetails ` ? and do u have to map that to get the result

Comment: From productDetails I distructure it and now Color ,size and other data which is view in the pic all are stored in variants

Comment: yeah, then u can map that data

Comment: `{productDetails.size[id].map((item)=>( //map here ))}` id is come form button see my example  `handleBtn` function

Comment: productDetails.size or variants.size? because size is inside variants

Comment: Thank you so much. I will finish it. After that I have one problem I want to send data into cart . here i used django rest api and reducer. Can i give me your linkedin id or skype

Comment: hello can you help me one things I need help

Comment: what's the help u need?

Comment: in this way I can't display size wise price.
now how to do it. Kindly help me
this is database pic link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386195/how-to-display-color-wise-size-price-and-quantity-in-react

Comment: in this database is it possible to display size wise price and quantity?